# HTML - I am trying to centre a paragraph in the middle of a page

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to get "Hello, World" in the dead centre of the page. It can be HTML or CSS I am a bit stuck on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. So far I can get it centered at the top of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <p style="font-family:tahoma;color:black;font-size:12px;text-align:center;">Hello, World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about including "top:50%;" in your paragraph's style attribute?

Comment: "top:50%;" doesn't do anything :(

Comment: @YagizOzturk well of course I have already tried that!!!! Why waste your time and my time posting that.

Comment: i said inspect not search. google also centers its logo.. on chrome try inspecting element

Comment: Easy to do with flexbox: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: p/s: Style attributes like "bgcolor" is deprecated. Try doing that with a stylesheet instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
p {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:50%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4KBVN/)**

Comment: how do I add this in? when previewing it, it only shows what I have added as opposed to styling my text

Comment: You can add the CSS to inline to the respective elements (not recommended) or add a stylesheet to your document and drop all the CSS in there (recommended).

Comment: This worked thanks, and thanks for letting me know the recommended ways! Its appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yBQky/)

Not the perfect solution, but very close to it. This works only if the size of the text doesn't change.

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-20px;/*Half of the text width*/
    margin-top:-5px;/*Half of the text height*/
}
```